# How to draw this picture use TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw this picture, i saw `\draw[domain=0:360,samples=1000] plot (\x:{2*sin(2*\x)});`,But they are not very similar,and my MWE as follows：

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  
\draw[domain=0:360,samples=1000] plot (\x:{2*sin(2*\x)});

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

now:
[image]

---

i want:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps like this?

```tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach\i in {0,90,180,270}
  \draw[rotate=\i] (0,0) -- (22.5:2) to [out=22.5,in=67.5,looseness=5] (67.5:2) -- cycle;
\foreach\i in {0,180}
  \draw[rotate=\i,dashed] (-22.5:3.25) arc (-22.5:22.5:3.25);
\fill (0,0) circle (1mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: trifoil]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[very thick]
    \newcommand{\R}{5}
        \foreach \i in {0,1,2,3}
            \draw (0,0) .. controls ++ (90*\i+20:\R) and ++ (90*\i+70:\R) .. (0,0);
        \draw[dashed]   (20:\R/2) arc (20:-20:\R/2)
                        (160:\R/2) arc (160:200:\R/2) ; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```